# Support for R in PyCharm gone after update

Tags: r, pycharm

I updated two plugins in PyCharm

> version 2021.2.1 (Professional Edition)
>
> Build #PY-212.5080.64 on August 25, 2021.

(but I forgot which ones).
Now the support for R is gone.
I see no R Console anymore and R scripts are recognized as text files.

[image]

even though the R plugin is installed:

[image]

Also I do not see an option to point to R in the *Project* Settings or the *Language & Frameworks* Settings.

[image]

What could be the issue and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you also have activated the R plugin. It might have been deactivated by the update. For activating the plugin again, go to

> Settings -> Plugins -> Installed

(Make sure you are not in Settings -> Plugins -> Marketplace!)

Then search for the plugin and enable it by pressing the checkbox.